Automatizar la descarga de unos archivos en PDF mediante PHP
Necesito automatizar la descarga de unos archivos en PDF a mi computadora, incluso si se puede también a otro servidor.
Tengo los enlaces de cada archivo, necesito descargar cada uno y guardarlo, el problema es que no sé cómo hacerlo automáticamente.
El procedimiento debe ser por PHP, tengo la data con los registros de las URL en MySql en mi servidor local.
Incluso, si se puede también pasar esos archivos directamente a otro servidor.

Buenas, este es un sitio para responder problemas con código existente, no hacer algo desde la nada. Deberías tener una idea de lo que quieres hacer ya.

Hola, ya tengo el sistema, pero descarga manualmente, necesito que sea automático.

Hola @aldoemartinez, podes utilizar file_get_contents para descargar el archivo remoto y file_put_contents para guardarlo en tu sistema loca. Intentalo y cuando tengas algún problema o no puedas avanzar, actualiza tu pregunta con el código.

Efectivamente use esa esas funciones.

Ya pude resolver el problema:
$ruta_archivo = $row['URL'];
        $nombre_archivo = "credencial_".$row['ESTADO']."_".$row['MUNICIPIO']."_".$row['CREDENCIAL']."_";
        $url = $ruta_archivo;
        $file_name = basename($url);
        if(file_put_contents($nombre_archivo.$file_name, file_get_contents($url))) { 
            echo "Descarga completada.";
        } 
        else { 
            echo "No hay registros."; 
        }


Es confuso.. este codigo descarga un archivo.. ahora la parte de automatizacion cual seria???
